# How to apply a discount to basket

Tags: php, mysql, discount

I'm trying to apply a discount to my basket for each pair of 2 items that cost £1.50 each but I can't seem to get the hang of it. I draw the results from two SQL queries/tables of 'discount' and 'basket' Here's the following I've tried:

```
$discount_count[] = 0;
$i = 0;
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($data_set2)) {                                 
  if ($row['product'] == $row2['product']) {
  foreach ($row2 as $current_row) {

     $actual_price = $row['product_cost'] * $row2['quantity'];
     $discount_total = round(($actual_price - ($actual_price * ($row2['discount_percent'] / 100))), 2);
     $total_price = $discount_total / $row2['quantity'] * $row['quantity'];
     $product_total = $row['product_cost'] * $row['quantity'];

     if ($i % 2 && $total_price * $row2['quantity'] > $row['product_cost'] * $row2['quantity']){
         echo "<br /><br />actual price per 2: £" . $actual_price;
         echo "<br />discount total: £" . $discount_total;
         echo "<br />actual minus discount: £";
         echo $actual_price - $discount_total;
         echo "<br />total price: £" . $total_price;
         echo "<br />product cost: £" . $product_total;

         $discount_count[] = $actual_price - $discount_total;
     }
         $i++;
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: What can't you do? Are you getting any errors? What is happening?

Comment: No errors, but the total sum of discounts gives an inaccurate number

Comment: inaccurate number in the sense of 23.14 instead of 23.15, or completely wrong numbers as 23.14 instead of 139.59?

Comment: Completely wrong numbers

Comment: Before you do any calculations in your code, echo out product_cost, quantity, and discount_percent to make sure you are getting the values you think you are getting.  Then do the calculations with those numbers by hand(or calculator) first.

Comment: product cost: 1.5
quantity: 2
discount: 16.67

actual price per 2: £3
discount total: £2.5
actual minus discount: £0.5
total price: £20
product cost: £24

Comment: You don't have to print them out here.  I just want you to ask yourself if those are the values you are hoping to input into the calculations.  If so, then manually do the calculations using a calculator to make sure you get what you want.  Then duplicate your manual calculations in your PHP code.

Comment: `$total_price = $discount_total / $row2['quantity'] * $row['quantity'];`  This doesn't look right.  Why are you dividing by quantity then multiplying by quantity.  That does nothing.